# How to call Some View returns function in Alert in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

How to call some view function in alert in swift

I have created this function for showing some data in alert(not in sheet or popover).how can I call this message in alert in swiftUI and please create if any extensions needed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/234Dp.png)

but I want to show that content in alert
private func popUpView() -> some View {

```
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        
        let correctAnswers = selectedQuestions.filter { question in
            question.answerJSON.contains { answer in
                answer.ans?.first?.t == question.userAnswer
            }
        }
        let totalQuestions = selectedQuestions.count
        let totalAnsweredQuestions = selectedQuestions.filter { $0.isAnswered }.count
        let wrongAnswers = totalAnsweredQuestions - correctAnswers.count
        let unansweredQuestions = totalQuestions - totalAnsweredQuestions
        
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            HStack(alignment: .center){
                
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(
                        Color(red: 194/255, green: 231/255, blue: 255/255, opacity: 1)
                    )
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(
                        Image("ic_Clock")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    )
                
                Text("Total Questions")
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                Spacer()
                Text(String(totalQuestions))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            .padding(10)
            Divider().background(Color.gray)
                .shadow(radius: 0.5)
            
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 194/255, green: 231/255, blue: 255/255, opacity: 1))
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(
                        Image("ic_Clock")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    )
                
                Text("Correct Answer")
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(String(correctAnswers.count))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            .padding(10)
            
            Divider().background(Color.gray)
                .shadow(radius: 0.5)
            
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 194/255, green: 231/255, blue: 255/255, opacity: 1))
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(
                        Image("ic_Clock")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    )
                
                Text("Wrong Answer")
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(String(wrongAnswers))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            .padding(10)
            
            Divider().background(Color.gray)
                .shadow(radius: 0.5)
            
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 194/255, green: 231/255, blue: 255/255, opacity: 1))
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .leading)
                    .overlay(
                        Image("ic_Clock")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    )
                
                Text("Unanswered")
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(String(unansweredQuestions))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            .padding(10)
        }
        Divider().background(Color.gray)
            .shadow(radius: 0.5)
        
        Text("Do you Want to Submit the test?")
            .font(Font.custom("avenir_bold", size: 14).bold())
        
            .padding(10)
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showPopUp = false
                }
            }) {
                Text("Close")
                    .modifier(CustomTextM(fontName: "avenir_bold", fontSize: 14, fontColor: Color.blue))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
            }
            
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    navigationSelection = 1
                    self.showPopUp = false
                }
                eventTest.endTest()
                navigateToHome = true
                
            }) {
                Text("Submit")
                    .modifier(CustomTextM(fontName: "avenir_bold", fontSize: 14, fontColor: Color.white))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(), isActive: $navigateToHome) { EmptyView() }
            )
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] and clarify the question